# How do I fetch a message in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command that sends an embed using user-provided args. I want to make a command that will edit the embed but I can't figure out how to fetch the message so I can edit it. My current code is this:

```
  @commands.command(description='Edits an embed message using the provided message link.')
  async def editembed(self, ctx, *, args=None):
    if args == None:
      #code here
    else:
      editConfig=args.split(" | ")
      if len(editConfig) > 5:
        await ctx.send("Too many arguments!")
      else:
        editConfig[0] = editConfig[0].lstrip("https://discord.com/channels/")
        linkConfig = editConfig[0].split("/")
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(linkConfig[1])
        messageID = await channel.fetch_message(linkConfig[2])
        embed=discord.Embed(title=editConfig[1], description=editConfig[3], colour=int(editConfig[2][1:],16))
        embed.set_footer(test=embedConfig[4])
        embed.timestamp = datetime.now()
        await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

The code gets stuck on the `fetch_message`. I've tried using `channel.fetch_message`, `discord.TextChannel.fetch_message` but nothing has worked. I'm using the commands framework from the discord.py-rewrite branch, the command is in a cog and the syntax for using the command would be `fa!editembed message link | Title | #Colour | Description | Footer`. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? Does it raise an error? If so, which?

Comment: It says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message' or it says 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_get_channel'

Comment: That indicates that the channel is not being found. I don' t remember off the top of my head if get_channel is the one picky about the argtype, but try converting the id to an integer before passing it

Comment: Tried that, didn't work either, returned similar responses

Comment: So I just tested the basics of your code with my own bot, and after converting the id to integer, the channel returned fine, whereas it would be `None` when passing the id as a string. Are you sure you used `self.bot.get_channel(int(linkConfig[1]))`?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but I left it for an hour or so to take care of a few other jobs and using it as an int has worked. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

await channel.fetch_message only works on id for example
await channel.fetch_message(12345)

Comment: I'm feeding the ID in the linkConfig list as a string as that worked previously for get_channel so I assumed it would work here.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message' is the traceback, I don't think the ID is the issue here :/

Comment: If it says that then linkConfig is returning None I believe :/

Comment: No, it's saying that the channel is the NoneType as I'm calling `channel.fetch_message`